# Unable to connect with GoPro HERO (2018)camera. I am unable to find code base which is able to connect with camera and record live stream actually

Tags: android, gopro

I have a GoPro HERO 2018 camera. I an developing an android application. In my application, I want to share live streaming on my android mobile.
I meant to say that, whatever is happening on GoPro camera, I want to display it on my android mobile through my own android application. For that I need APIs through which I can connect and able to do live 
Currently I am using [this link](https://github.com/takyonxxx/Gopro-Manager-Android) , but unable to do live streaming.
Please help me and feel free to ask any query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have solved my problem.
For this, I have used an FFMPEG command.

I have used VLC library (that can display udp stream).
With the ffmpeg library, use this command:
String[] cmd = {"-f", "mpegts", "-i", "udp://:8554", "-f", "mpegts", "udp://127.0.0.1:8555/gopro?pkt_size=64"};
and with VLC library, display the stream "udp://@:8555/gopro"
and then you can see the live stream.

Steps are-

1. Connect with GoPro WiFi.
2. Hit GoPro API http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/execute?p1=gpStream&a1=proto_v2&c1=restart.
3. Create FFMpeg instance and first call `ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {...}`
   Leave its overrided methods blank.

Then call `ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {...}`
In its onProgress methos, hit again GoPro API http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/execute?p1=gpStream&a1=proto_v2&c1=restart

4. Using VLC library, create your media player and set your VideoView/SurfaceView there.
5. Now you will be able for live streaming from GoPro HERO 2018.

Note:- This is not working on higher API level of android (above 20). I have used Volley for calling GoPro API.

May this will help anyone.

Comment: Hi Rahul, I am able to get udp stream but there is leg. Do u have any workaround for same.

Comment: Hello Praveen, I am also stuck at that and there is nothing I have found to solve the problem. Even the video is not clear and smooth.

Comment: goPro introduced wsdk as sdk for mobile apps year ago but its not publicly available right now.